# Multiple join not joining as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I have the following tables

```
table 2 with a fk to table 1
table 3 with a fk to table 1
```

In table 2 I have two rows linked to table 1
In table 3 I have one row linked table 1

I am trying to produce a table that has

```
| table1 pk  | table 2 pk | null |
| table1 pk  | table 2 pk | null |
| table1 pk  | null | table 3 pk |
```

However when I try the following I get

```
select tab1.id, tab2.id, tab3.id
from table1 tab1 
left join tab2 on tab1.id = tab2.tab1_id
left join tab3 on tab1.id = tab3.tab1_id
```

gives this table

```
| table1 pk  | table 2 pk | table 3 pk |
| table1 pk  | table 2 pk | table 3 pk |
```

Can anyone help with this SQL please?

Thanks in advance

EDIT

I think I may have simplified this a bit too much. Ideally output would be

```
| table1 pk  | table 2 pk |
| table1 pk  | table 3 pk |
| table1 pk  | table 3 pk |
```

Once I get this join working it will be added to another massive query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One unusual solution is

```
select coalesce(t2.tab1_id, t3.tab1_id) pk,
   t2.pk, t3.pk
from table2 t2 
   full join table3 t3
       on t3.tab1_id = t2.tab1_id
where exists (select * from table1
              where pk in (t2.tab1_id, t3.tab1_id)
```

NOTE (Edit)  As noted by Andriy M in comment, the where clause only eliminates rows from table2 and table3 where the FK does not exist in table1, which cannot exist if FK constraints have been properly applied to table2 and table3.

Comment: @RNJ or Charles: Doesn't this return exactly the same output as the query in the original post (which I understood was not what was needed)? And by the way, if relational integrity is enforced on the tables, the `where` clause is redundant.

Comment: @Anrily,  No the sql in the question would mix data from table 2 and table3 on same row of output.  but, yes, the where clause only eliminates rows from table2 and table3 where the FK does not exist in table1, which, as you adroitly recognized, cannot exist if FK constraints have been properly applied to table2 and table3.

Comment: [I'm still not convinced about the output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4bf7f/4), sorry. Could you demonstrate a case where the two queries would return different results? (Assuming there are no "rogue" FKs in either table2 or table3)

Comment: Also, I think there's a typo in your query: the `t1.pk` should probably be `t3.pk`.

Comment: @Andrily,  yes you're correct --- fixed it...   an e.g., is just add more rows to tab1...

Comment: Yes, their query would return `tab1` entries that had no matches in either of the other two tables, I did miss that. Well, if that is what actually was the issue, the question turns out remarkably confusing and misleading. But, well, they've ultimately got their solution and I'm happy for them. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything crazy here

```
WITH TAB1
    AS (SELECT 1 AS ID FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 AS ID FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 AS ID FROM DUAL),
    TAB2
    AS (SELECT 1 AS TAB1_ID, 'A' AS ID FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 AS TAB1_ID, 'B' AS ID
        FROM DUAL),
    TAB3
    AS (SELECT 3 AS TAB1_ID, 'C' AS ID
        FROM DUAL)
SELECT
      TAB1.ID,
      COALESCE ( TAB2.ID,
               TAB3.ID )
FROM
      TAB1
      LEFT JOIN TAB2
          ON TAB1.ID = TAB2.TAB1_ID
      LEFT JOIN TAB3
          ON TAB1.ID = TAB3.TAB1_ID;

1   A   
2   B   
3   C
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I actually need them so that they are all in one column because this is an input for another massive query. Is it easier if I have them all in one column? I may have simplified this a bit too much

Comment: @RNJ  what do you want to see as output

Comment: I updated the answer, but the credit should be given to Charles Bretana. He got it in the first shot.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join to the result of a union:

```
SELECT
  t1.table1pk,
  t23.table2pk,
  t23.table3pk
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT table2pk, NULL AS table3pk, table1fk
  FROM table2

  UNION ALL

  SELECT NULL AS table2pk, table3pk, table1fk
  FROM table3
) t23
ON t1.table1pk = t23.table1fk
;
```

Or you could use a union of two joins' results:

```
SELECT
  t1.table1pk,
  t2.table2pk,
  NULL AS table3pk
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.table1pk = t2.table1fk

UNION ALL

SELECT
  t1.table1pk,
  NULL AS table2pk,
  t3.table3pk
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table3 t3
ON t1.table1pk = t3.table1fk
;
```

Both methods could be adapted to produce the two-column version of the desired output:

- a join to a union:

  ```
  SELECT
    t1.table1pk,
    t23.otherpk
  FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT table2pk AS otherpk, table1fk
    FROM table2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT table3pk AS otherpk, table1fk
    FROM table3
  ) t23
  ON t1.table1pk = t23.table1fk
  ;
  ```
- a union of joins:

  ```
  SELECT
    t1.table1pk,
    t2.table2pk AS otherpk
  FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.table1pk = t2.table1fk

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    t1.table1pk,
    t3.table3pk AS otherpk
  FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table3 t3
  ON t1.table1pk = t3.table1fk
  ;
  ```

Comment: thanks @AndriyM. My example in my questions was actually a bit too sinmplified. The first union all solution was what I used in my code.